# how to use the quantile() function to split a variable into 3 classes of identical values

Tags: r

please a have a dataframe called wine with variables among which is the variable
Spice of integer type.

I will like to split this variable(Spice) using the quantile() function into 3 classes of identical values

NB :USING the quantile()  function please

Comment: When asking for help, you should provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data and the desired output for that input. What does "3 classes of identical values" mean exactly? And why would you require the `quantile()` function specifically?

Answer (score 1):

Like MrFlick said, your question is ill formed. Do you want to split what? `Spice` or `wine`? If `Spice` is integer the quantiles will generally not split it in groups of equal sizes. Anyway here is code to do something similar to what you've tried to ask.

```
set.seed(4124)
wine <- data.frame(Spice = sample(5, 20, TRUE))
qq <- quantile(wine$Spice, probs = seq(0, 1, 1/3))
split(wine, findInterval(wine$Spice, qq, all.inside = TRUE))
```